# WPF ComboBox PreviewMouseDown

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox

I have a combobox that is editable and a textbox.

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="86,149,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="282,150,0,0" IsEditable="True" PreviewMouseDown="ComboBox_PreviewMouseDown"/>
```

I don't understand why `ComboBox_PreviewMouseDown` does not trigger, when the focus is on the textbox and I click on the combobox. It just highlights the text in the combobox and sets the focus. Clicking in the combobox when it already has the focus, `PreviewMouseDown` fires.

Is that what's happening here? Why is a `PreviewMouseDown` in an unfocused combobox not working?

Comment: Well, it doesn't work the way you want. It doesn't really matter why they designed it that way. What are you doing in that event? Would the GotFocus event be a better choice? What if the user tabs into the combobox instead of clicking on it?

Comment: I have a popup with a combobox. Also have a WebBrower control to display pdf documents. The problem I am facing is, that when pdf has the keyboard focus and I click into the combobox to edit the text, the text is selected, but all keyboard actions are still send to the pdf in the WebBroser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `ComboBox.IsEditable` is set to `True`, the `ComboBox` internally sets the focus (and keyboard focus) to the edit `TextBox` to make it instantly available for text input. This makes total sense as the intention when clicking the edit `TextBox` is always to enter or edit some text. Otherwise, the user would have to click the `TextBox` twice to make it receive focus for text input (keyboard focus).
So, to prevent focus stealing, the author marked the `MouseDown` event as handled i.e. `RoutedEventArgs.Handled` is set to `true`. (This is the reason why most non-preview events are marked handled by most controls).

Also, the author wanted to prevent the moving of the caret when clicked into the edit `TextBox` for the first time (to give it focus): the `PreviewMouseDown` event's `RoutedEventArgs.Handled` will *only* be set to `true`, if the edit `TextBox` has no keyboard focus and the drop-down panel is closed. (That's why the second click into the `TextBox` will pass through to be handled by an added event handler).

To achieve the behavior you expect, you have to handle the `UIElement.PreviewGotKeyboardFocus` event or the attached `Keyboard.PreviewGotKeyboardFocus`event on the `ComboBox`.

Alternatively register the event handler using the `UIElement.AddHandler` method and set the `handledEventsToo` parameter to `true`:

```
this.MyComboBox.AddHandler(
  UIElement.PreviewMouseDownEvent, 
  new RoutedEventHandler(MyComboBox_PreviewMouseDown), 
  true);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221807/discussion-on-answer-by-bioniccode-wpf-combobox-previewmousedown).

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this same issue myself. A simple and effective workaround is to wrap your `ComboBox` in a lightweight `ContentPresenter`, then attach your `PreviewMouseDown` handler to that, like so:

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="MyComboBoxWrapper"
    PreviewMouseDown="MyComboBoxWrapper_PreviewMouseDown">

    <ContentPresenter.Content>
        <ComboBox x:Name="MyComboBox" />
    </ContentPresenter.Content>

</ContentPresenter>
```

Additionally, since this control gets the `PreviewMouseDown` event before the `ComboBox` does, you not only can use it to pre-process events before the `ComboBox` even sees them, but you can cut off the `ComboBox` entirely by setting the event arg's `handled` property to 'true.'

Works like a charm! No subclassing or other tricks needed and it only requires a lightweight control in the tree!

### Notes

As some may have considered, technically you could attach the `PreviewMouseDown` event to *any* ancestor of your `ComboBox`, but you then may have to include logic in that handler to determine if you're actually clicking on the `ComboBox` vs something else.

By using an explicit `ContentPresenter` (an incredibly lightweight element that itself doesn't have any rendering logic. It simply hosts other elements), you now have a dedicated `PreviewMouseDown` handler just for this control.  Plus, it makes it more portable should you need to move it around since the two items can travel together.

Comment: I've used the ContentPresenter trick too. Very easy solution and more understandable/readable than other ways to do it.